# How to correctly display images using the getResources method?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am creating basically a shopping cart app and I am trying to populate a listView with images of the items. So currently everything else is displayed just fine like the size, store, description, price, etc. All this information is being retrieved from my existing database and put into the listView. For the images, I have put the names of the images into a column in my database called ID and I have put the actual images into my drawable folder. To make the images show up with their respective item, I am using the getResources method, but for some reason, it isn't working, it won't show the image. I have posted the code below, and you'll see the getResources method in my ListItemAdapter.java. If someone could figure this out and fix it, that would be great.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing/databases/";
    public static String DB_NAME = "healthysizing";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_USER = "Shirts";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        if(myDB!=null){
            myDB.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    /*public List<String> getAllUsers() {
        List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c;

        try {
            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER , null);
            if(c == null) return null;

            String name;
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                name = c.getString(5);
                listUsers.add(name);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
        }


        db.close();

        return listUsers;
    } */

    /*public List<Item> getAllShirts() {

        List<Item> shirtList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER; //query to get all the shirts
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
                item.setBrand(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setStore(cursor.getString(3));
                item.setDescription(cursor.getString(5));
                shirtList.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return shirtList;

    }*/

    public ArrayList<Item> getAllSearchedShirts(String brand) {

        ArrayList<Item> shirtList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER + " WHERE Brand LIKE '" + brand + "' ORDER BY Price ASC"; //query to get all the shirts for brand typed in
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setBrand(cursor.getString(0));
                item.setStore(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
                item.setDescription(cursor.getString(3));
                item.setSize(cursor.getString(4));
                item.setID(cursor.getString(6));
                shirtList.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return shirtList;

    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getAllShirts() {

        ArrayList<Item> shirtList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER + " ORDER BY Price ASC"; //query to get all the shirts
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setBrand(cursor.getString(0));
                item.setStore(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
                item.setDescription(cursor.getString(3));
                item.setSize(cursor.getString(4));
                item.setID(cursor.getString(6));
                shirtList.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return shirtList;

    }

    /*public Cursor getShirtsData() {
        String SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM" + TB_USER;
        return myDB.rawQuery(SQLQuery, null);
    } */


    /***
     * Open database
     * @throws android.database.SQLException
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Copy database from source code assets to device
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        try {
            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    /***
     * Check if the database doesn't exist on device, create new one
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {

        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // PRIVATE METHODS
    // ---------------------------------------------

    /***
     * Check if the database is exist on device or not
     * @return
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
        }
        if (tempDB != null)
            tempDB.close();
        return tempDB != null ? true : false;
    }

}
```

**ListItemAdapter.java**

```
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public final class ListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> shirtItems) {
        super(context, 0, shirtItems);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Get the data item for this position
        Item item = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout_shirts, parent, false);
        }

        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView brand = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_brand);
        TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_price);
        TextView store = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_store);
        TextView size = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_size);
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_shirt_description);
        ImageView shirtsImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_shirts);

        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        brand.setText("Brand:" + "  " + item.getBrand());
        price.setText("Price:" + "  $" + item.getPrice());
        store.setText("Store:" + "  " + item.getStore());
        size.setText("Size:" + "  " + item.getSize());
        description.setText("Description:" + "  " + item.getDescription());

        Context context = parent.getContext();
        int shirtsID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(item.getID(), "drawable", ListItemAdapter.class.getPackage().getName());
        //int shirtsID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("packagename:drawable/" + item.getID(), null, null);
        shirtsImage.setImageResource(shirtsID);

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**shirtsActivity.java**

```
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class shirtsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shirts);

        final SearchView shirtViewShirts = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView3);
        final DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
        final ListView listView;
        final ListAdapter shirtsAdapter;

        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShirts);
        //List<Item> shirtsList = dbhelper.getAllShirts();
        ArrayList<Item> shirtsList = dbhelper.getAllShirts();

        if (shirtsList != null) {
            //shirtsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, shirtsList);
            shirtsAdapter = new ListItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), shirtsList);
            listView.setAdapter(shirtsAdapter);
        }

        shirtViewShirts.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                //query = query.toLowerCase();
                //query = Character.toString(query.charAt(0)).toUpperCase()+query.substring(1);

                ListAdapter searchedShirtsAdapter;
                Log.e("Brand: ", query);
                ArrayList<Item> searchedShirtsList = dbhelper.getAllSearchedShirts(query);

                if (searchedShirtsList != null) {
                    searchedShirtsAdapter = new ListItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), searchedShirtsList);
                    listView.setAdapter(searchedShirtsAdapter);
                }

                listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_shirts_message));

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }

        });

    }

}
```

**Item.java**

```
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

public class Item {

    private String brand;
    private String size;
    private String price;
    private String store;
    private String description;
    private String ID;
    private String gender;

    public Item() {

    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setStore(String store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {this.description = description;}

    public String getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getGender() {return gender; }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getDescription() {return description; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (this.brand + "  " + this.store + "  " + this.price + "  " + this.description);
    }

}
```

**item_layout_shirts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_price"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_brand"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_shirt_price"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_shirt_price"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_shirt_price"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_store"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_shirt_brand"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_shirt_brand"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_shirt_brand"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_size"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_shirt_store"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_shirt_store"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txt_shirt_store" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add item to Cart"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_shirt_description"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image_view_shirts"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_shirt_size"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/shirts"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/txt_shirt_description"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_view_shirts"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_shirts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#29A9D2"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/shirt">

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="358dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView3"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:queryHint="Search for specific brand" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewShirts"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_shirts_message"
            android:text="No Results Found"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why is your code enclosed in JavaScript code blocks? It won't run!

Comment: Yeah I know, I just wanted to put it there so everyone can see it.

Comment: It's enough to select your code blocks and hit `Ctrl` + `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Analysis:**

*Actually to access the drawable resources defined in your apk, when you are accessing them dynamically you have to refer them with package name*

---

### Quoting your code

```
String itemName = item.getID(); 
int name = Integer.parseInt(itemName); 
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(name); 
shirtsImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

---

### Sample from my Projects on how this must be done (modify below code to your needs)

```
    Drawable res1 = null;
    String uri1 = null;
    try {
        //First image
        uri1 = "@drawable/"+imageSplitted[0];
        int imageResource1 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        res1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //int imageResource1 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        res1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);// Default image
    }
```

### using above code do something like this

```
    Drawable res1 = null;
    String uri1 = null;
    try {
        //First image
        String itemName = item.getID(); 
        uri1 = "@drawable/"+itemName;
        int imageResource1 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        res1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //int imageResource1 = context.getResources().getIdentifier(uri1, null, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        res1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);// Default image
    }
```

***Hope this helps !***

Answer (score 1):

You can access Drawables in res/drawable in a much easier way.

`context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.<drawablename>`

Comment: So going off of what you just said this is what I did. So in my database, the ID's of the items are strings like J1, K1. So this is why first I'm converting them into ints and then doing what you said and still the same thing, it doesn't show the images:                                                                      String itemName = item.getID();
        int name = Integer.parseInt(itemName);
        Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(name);
        shirtsImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);